# How could I refactor this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

Given the following helper method.

```
def link_tags(collection)
  tags = collection.split(',')

  tags.map.each do |tag|
    if tag == tags.last
      content_tag(:a, tag, href: tags_filter_post_path(tag) )
    else
      content_tag(:a, tag, href: tags_filter_post_path(tag) ) + ', '
    end        
  end.reduce(:<<)
end
```

How could I do a little refactor on this?

EDIT: The final code after the refactoring suggested.

```
def link_tags(collection)  
  collection.split(',').collect do |tag| 
    link = ""
    link += link_to tag, tags_filter_post_path(tag)
  end.join(', ').html_safe
end
```

Comment: Why are you calling `each` on `map`?

Comment: Code review questions belong on [CodeReview.SE](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.Com/).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you, didn't know about CodeReview.SE ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def link_tags(collection)
  collection.split(',').map do |tag| 
    link_to tag, tag_filter_post_path(tag)
  end.join(', ')
end
```

Comment: Didn't think to change it to a `link_to`—nice (+1). I decided to leave the `tags` variable since I feel it helps add some context to what's going on, but obviously that's all subjective.

Comment: Best one in my opinion. I'd just switch `.map` with `.collect`, as I think it makes more sense. :P

Comment: I agree that `.collect` is clearer, though I see `.map` used a lot more often and is a method every Ruby programmer should know.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post with the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `join` instead of mucking around with handling the last element specially (which also won't work the way you're doing it unless the elements are unique) and then concatenating after. The call to `each` is also redundant.

```
def link_tags(collection)
  tags = collection.split(',')
  tags.map do |tag|
    content_tag(:a, tag, href: tags_filter_post_path(tag))
  end.join(', ')
end
```

Comment: outputs: `<a href="/posts/tags/important">important</a>, <a href="/posts/tags/test">test</a> as a text and not a link as I wish.

Comment: using `.reduce(:<<)` solves this problem, but it seems not work with `join`

Answer (score 0):

Try this(with `link_to` as suggested by xnm):

```
def link_tags(collection)
  collection.split(',').each {|tag| link_to tag, tag_filter_post_path(tag)}.join(', ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For code re-factoring http://refactormycode.com is a good option

This is the Ruby section:

http://refactormycode.com/codes/recent/ruby